# Wires from car battery to solenoid catching fire after connecting a second solenoid

Tags: mosfet, avr, solenoid

I have two solenoids connected to my AVR and car battery:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRqcEo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But when I start switching them the circuit burns up (literally there was fire).

The lines connected to the solenoid is what caught fire.  The switching frequency is probably like 1 or 2 Hz.

Here is some data on the solenoids (I unfortunately cannot find a part number on them any where):

- Switch at 12V
- .58 Amps running
- 2.94 Amps switching
- 16V spikes when switching

What did I do wrong here?

FYI: We were able to get this to work (without fire) with just a single solenoid, but adding the second causes these issues.

Comment: What part started burning?

Comment: What is switching frequency? What kind of solenoid?

Comment: @KarlKarlsom The wires going to the solenoid caught fire

Comment: Extremely weak gate drive, high Miller capacitance = severe oscillation? It should burn the FET and/or relay though. Diode connected in reverse?

Comment: @winny No the diode is connect correctly (I could not have gotten them to work individually if the diode was hooked up backward)

Comment: if FET Ron is like 100 mOhm (which it would be normal) then you may expect more than 100A current flow through selenoid and the wire. Why don't you put an adjusted resistor in series to the selenoid 12/ 1A = 12 Ohm.

Comment: Probably the 1N4148 is not a good choice here. You don't need high speed diode here. 1N4001 will be better.

Comment: @soosaisteven I was hoping to just use what I had in stock

Comment: Check Vds with an oscilloscope.

Comment: @winny Don't have a scope

Comment: Oh, then you are in a tight spot my friend.

Comment: Did you omit to draw the fuse between your circuitry and the battery? It *really* should have one.

Comment: @AndrewMorton We do have a fuse now (after the fire indecent)

Comment: All the above comments appear to be addressing the input side of the solenoid, since that's all you drew and discussed.  Since the actual fault (fire) occurred on the output side of the solenoid, you need to show a drawing of that part of the circuit, and describe what all is connected there.

Answer (score 4):

Wires overheat because of over current.

Get out your multi-meter and measure the current in the wire.

(BTW, you mention 16 volt spikes, yet you say you don’t have an oscilloscope. Hmmm ? )

If the solenoid doesn’t fully engage (pull in), then you may be drawing a continuous current of  2.94 amps. Use a wire size able to handle 6 amps (both solenoids) continuous and the wires won’t catch on fire. Then you can find  other problems.

EDIT 1 :  You also should change diode to a diode that can handle a PEAK forward current of at least 3 amps. (per suggestion by @soosai steven). The 1N4148 is rated at 400mA recurrent peak forward current.

Comment: I Have a multi-meter (set to measure max voltage)

Comment: measuring current is not the same as measuring voltage; different setting on your multimeter. Still: **don't use your multimeter to measure the current**. If a thick wire burns, then your multimeter will, in the best case, blow its internal fuse.

Comment: what Marla is hinting at, @DarthRubik, regarding the 16V spikes: these spikes are extremely short. It's both extremely unlikely that they will be that small, and that you would be able to observe them with a multimeter.

Answer (score 3):

What you've inadvertently built is a kind of harmonics-generating device.

Let's call your solenoids A and B.

Lets also act as if your solenoids are just their inductance.

The reason you've added the Diodes is that the moment you suddenly change the current going through a coil/inductance, the differential U/I relation of the inductance comes into effect

\$v(t)= L\, \frac{d\,i(t)}{dt}\$

In other words: the moment you switch off A's MOSFET, you generate a huge change in \$i(t)\$ with a negative slope, and hence, your solenoid generates a huge negative voltage spike – which should be caught by the normally reverse diode. Now, your diodes are woefully undersized for that job. They'll probably get damaged very quickly, and what's more important here that they can't get the energy out of the coil quick enough.

What happens then is that the reverse voltage adds up with the battery voltage. Suddenly, and for a very short period of time, voltage across B is inversed. B doesn't care, at first, because, resolving the equation above for the current \$i(t)\$

\$ i(t) = \frac1L \int\limits_{\tau=T_0}^t{ v(\tau)\,d\tau}\, + I_0 \$

and your quick sign change doesn't contribute much to the integral.

Now that means that there's still current flowing into B, which doesn't come from the battery – it comes from the energy stored in the magnetic field in A.

Guess what happens next: The energy from A ends up in B, increasing B's voltage above that of your battery. You charge the battery. Now, that has to stop at some point, namely, when the the coil gets more and more charged. Uh-oh. Now we've got negative \$\frac{d\,i}{dt}\$ again.

You just built something that oscillates energy between A and B, and dumps it over the diodes, cables and into your battery. There's probably immensely high ripple currents in your supply leads, that are very effective at heating metal :).

The proper solution to this is a bit hard. Adding a series resistor to the coils is a first step, because that will dampen the oscillations, but it will also lead to energy loss/heat during non-switching operation.

Higher-current diodes are a must.

Proper cabling, too. The two solenoids should be connected as close to the battery as possible so that oscillating current would have to travel a long way.